# Webpack 4 - Style-loader/url not working

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I'm having my webpack set up and it's running all fine, but in development it is serving my compiled scss stylesheets inline instead of using an URL.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader"},
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
                    }
                },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I grabbed the [docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#url) and read up on how to use a single `CSS` file instead. I updated my webpack config to the following and since all loaders are running in reverse order this should be working;

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                { loader: "style-loader/url"}, 
                { loader: "file-loader" },
                { loader: "css-loader" },
                { loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        plugins: () => [require('autoprefixer')]
                    }
                },
                { loader: "sass-loader" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It results in no errors, and inserts the following stylesheet into my header;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="6bbafb3b6c677b38556511efc7391506.scss">
```

As you can see it's creating an scss file, whereas I was expecting a .css file. I tried moving the file-loader around but that didn't work either and resulted in several crashes. Any idea how to turn this into a working css file?

I **can't** use mini-css-extract in my dev env since I'm using HMR. I already got this working on my prod env.

Update: *When removing css-loader it compiles and shows my css applied to the page. But when I inspect the elements everything is on line 1 and the file it refers to can not be found*

I'm importing my css like this in `index.js` by the way;

```
import '../css/styles.scss';
```

Comment: What does “HRM” mean/stand for?

Comment: Sorry, made a typo there. I meant HMR, Hot Module Replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You can install extract-text-webpack-plugin for webpack 4 using:

npm i -D extract-text-webpack-plugin@next

The you can define the following constants:

```
// Configuring PostCSS loader
const postcssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: [
                // Write future-proof CSS and forget old preprocessor specific syntax.
                // It transforms CSS specs into more compatible CSS so you don’t need to wait for browser support.
                require('postcss-preset-env')()
        ]
    }
};

// Configuring CSS loader
const cssloader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
       importLoaders: 1
    }
};
```

Then in your SASS loader section, you can use the following:

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    use: [cssloader, postcssLoader, 'sass-loader']
})
```

Then in you plugins section, you need to use the following:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].css'
)
```

Now suppose that your entry section is like below:

```
    entry: {
        app: 'index.js'
    }
```

The generated CSS will be named as app.css and placed inside the css folder.

Another useful plugins for handling these type of post creating operations are:

HtmlWebpackPlugin and HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin

Working with these plugins along with extract-text-webpack-plugin gives you a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with webpack, after searching for a long time i found the soluton of combining a few plugins:

This is my result config: (as a bonus it preserves your sass sourcemaps;))

```
watch: true,
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'source-map',
plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "[name].css", //make sure you use this format to prevent .scss extention in the hot reload file
        chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
],
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'css-hot-loader', //5. this will hot load all the extracted css.
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, //4 this will extract all css
                {
                    loader: "css-loader", //3. this is where the fun starts
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "postcss-loader", //2. add post css
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader", //1 . you can ingore the globImporter
                    options: {
                        importer: globImporter(),
                        includePaths: ["node_modules"],
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```